# HTML bookmark returns to homepage

Tags: html

I have a simple bookmark on the page that takes me to he main content:

In header:

```
<a href="#content">Skip to main content</a>
```

In page:

```
<div id="content">
```

Clicking the link on any content page takes me back to the homepage of the site (index).

I have checked the source code and the id is present on the page (only one reference) and fails across ie, ff and chrome.

Clicking on the link on the actual homepage works as expected where it scrolls to the id.

Any idea what causes this and anyway to stop it going back to the homepage?

Comment: you put id on href  so going back homepage.need to remove it. you can use other Id or class

Comment: @VishalParmar That's wrong, she/he is using html anchors (not links). But I think the problem is in the `javascript/jQuery` of your page. Can you share us?

Comment: @Roy he/she put the id in anchors href so redirect in content class of home index.mu suggestion is you can change Id name

Comment: @VishalParmar I have tried a different id but the same result

Comment: @Roy Its on a beta site, what should I be looking for, there is no preventdefault being used

Comment: @TJ15 I don't know, we can't help you if there's not all the information provided. We need to be able to reproduce your problem, and we can't.

Comment: @Roy Thanks Roy, as you know sometimes this is not always possible, the hope was someone may have had a similar issue and could share their experience. Thanks for your help anyway